# Can I batch move many files in many separate subdirectories/folders to a single main one in windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, batch

I have a ton of files in locations like this:

```
C:/Users/(Username)/Desktop/(Parent-Collection name)/(filename1)/(filename1).ext

.../(filename2)/(filename2).ext

.../(filename3)/(filename3).ext
```

I am trying to batch move the `.ext` files to the parent folder so it's:

`C:/Users/(Username)/Desktop/(Parent-Collection name)/(filename1).ext`

Essentially eliminating the need for the sub folder, much like taking dividers out of a school-binder.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do this one with [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), which I'd recommend to anyone who's (still??) running the M$ Windoze spyware.

Something like this should work.  Execute it in the directory `C:/Users/(Username)/Desktop/(Parent-Collection name)/` (which in cygwin would be referred to as `/cygdrive/c/Users/(Username)/Desktop/(Parent-Collection name)/)`:

```
for i in `find . -name "*" -type f`; 
    do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/.*\/\([^/]*\)/\1/'`; 
done
```

That will move all files in all directories below `(Parent-Collection name)` to `(Parent-Collection name)`.  Specifically, this is a `do` loop with the index `i` looping through every file from the present directory on down.  That's what the `find` command lists.  You can look up the syntax by running `man find`.  Then what you execute is to move (`mv`) that file (`$i`) to the new location.  That new location is specified by the original filename (`echo $i`) run through the stream editor (`sed`, which you can look up with `man sed`) which is set to strip off the path, leaving the base filename.

I suggest testing it (make a directory with a couple of sub-directories containing some empty text files or something) and make sure to have a backup!

You may then want to remove all the (now empty) directories below your present directory:

```
for i in `find . -name "*" -type d`; 
    do rmdir $i; 
done
```

The only thing different here is that you are telling `find` to look for directories (`-type d`) rather than files (`-type f`) and then removing those directories (`rmdir`, which only works on empty directories).

Isn't linux cool?  Cygwin gives you some of the power of linux and could be a first step to getting you comfortable enough with it that some day you might even find it in you to move to something like Ubuntu.  :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm using one of the older windows back when it wasn't crappy :)   Wish there was a windows program or command to do this so I didn't have to essentially run a linux environment.  Also, I'm planning to do a triple-boot setup once I build my replacement for this computer.

Comment: Multi-boot isn't really such a good idea these days. Best to use one OS and then if you need others, run them _under_ your main OS.  It's very easy with Virtualbox (VB).  So install VB in Win and then install Ubuntu in VB - or the reverse, or any other OS.  The problem with multi-boot is that the OS's don't "talk" to each other as you're only running one at a time.  That's what I did. I started with cygwin, then I moved to ubuntu in VB, then I move to ubuntu with Win in VB for the few things that came up.  Finally, I just jettisoned Win altogether.

Comment: I'm planning on having the OSes with their programs on one SSD while having all my data on a separate HDD if that makes a difference so hopefully I won't need them "talking to eachother". Also, virtualbox does introduce some overhead and stuff as well over running natively.

Comment: True enough with the overhead, but that really depends on what you're wanting to do.  You're not going to game in VB, that's for sure!  The multi-boot approach will leave you stuck when you're in one OS wanting to do something in the other and not wanting to go through rebooting for that.  Also, say you're using Win, with NTFS and linux with ... ext4? btrfs?  You'll find that these filesystems don't interoperate very well.  Anyway, I tried it somewhere along the way and very quickly concluded that it wasn't really an option.  You may need to try it for yourself.

Comment: I opened up Cygwin and navigated to the correct directory, but I'm having trouble understanding the command you typed. Can you break the parts down and explain it so I can understand better?

Comment: I'm trying to enter it but nothing seems to happen. :S

Comment: Make sure you get the quote marks right.  There is a difference between `\`` and `'` and `"`.

Comment: Also, you can maybe test it this way.  You can replace the line `do ...;` by simply `do echo $i;`.  That will echo (print out) all the file names.  That way you'll see if you're looping over the right things, at least.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to do anything. Oh well, thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, it works on my machine (I tested).  Perhaps you'll play with it a bit more.  Good luck.

Comment: Powershell can handle this common task nicely. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Powershell, although we don't know what version of Windows you are using.

```
$sourcefolder = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\ParentCollectionName"

$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $sourcefolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIScontainer -eq $false}
ForEach ($file in $allfiles)
    {
        $destinationfolder = Split-Path -Parent $file.Directory.FullName
        Move-Item $file.FullName $destinationfolder
    }
```

All files in sub directories of `$sourcefolder` will be moved to the `ParrentCollectionName` folder. Then you can delete the empty subfolders.

[Source](http://www.marcvalk.net/2012/02/powershell-moving-my-photos-up-one-folder/)